# How to determine the damping factor in Levenberg-Marquardt?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, least-squares

From the algorithm, we can see that it tries different damping factor until it gets a good one by the error. Is the damping factor related to the eigenvalues of the Hessian matrix?

Answer (score 1):

The damping factor is expressed in terms of the objective function that one seeks to minimise, as described in [A new approach for determining damping factors in Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm for solving an inverse heat conduction problem](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0017931016331568) (2017).